# Drop Multiple Column Using single Alter

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I searched a lot on web, but couldn't find the answer for dropping multiple columns in single alter statement using SQL Server 2008.

I tried following query

```
ALTER TABLE TableToDropColumn DROP (Field2, Field3)
```

but it throws an error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '('.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE TableToDropColumn DROP COLUMN Field2, Field3
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4b728/1)

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER TABLE TableToDropColumn DROP Field2, DROP Field3
```

Comment: ALTER TABLE TableToDropColumn DROP COLUMN Field2, DROP COLUMN Field3.... is the only way, that works in Postgres.

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER TABLE TableToDropColumn DROP COLUMN Field2, Field3
```

**On a side note:**

You may also need to know how to get rid of the wasted space which is created after the above command.You can do `ALTER TABLE ... REBUILD`. Actually `DROP COLUMN` does not physically remove the data and the space is consumed even for records added after the columns were dropped. So thats why you need to use `ALTER TABLE ... REBUILD` to get rid of the wasted space